# setTimeout for long periods of time (up to 24h)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I made a website that should run a 'cronjob' every 24 hours, however, I used setTimeout and a function to calculate the time in milliseconds until it should run again. I noticed that the cronjob used to run fine for quite a while, but recently it's been bugging. I don't see any errors, it seems like the setTimeout is not called at all.

I'm wondering, as I have been told this before, is it really that bad to use setTimeout for such long times? If so, what else should I use as an alternative?

Comment: I have worked on something similar.we maintained the timeout throughout the session ..which can go on upto 24hrs. so we made some scripts to fire at a fixed time irrespective of the timeout

Comment: I'd like it to be part of the same script

Comment: Why are you not doing it server side?

Comment: I'm talking about NodeJS, this is all serverside

Comment: https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron

Comment: we use python scripts.trigger them based on the time.Do you want me to post that script ?

Comment: @RubenRutten sorry - missed the tag - I was imagining this in a browser...

Comment: @BhandariS I rather use node-cron, as suggested by Andreas

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is way too old, but just to clarify that set timeout is off by small margins, and shouldn't be used for longer periods of time as far as i know.